# How to validate two fields that should be equal in Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I am using express-validator for the first time and I can't find a way to assert if two fields are equal (if that can be done at all).

**Example**: A form containing 2 times an email address (one as standard confirmation) is submitted. I want to check that the fields match.

I found a workaround by myself which works but I wonder if I'm not just doing something unnecessary. Here is the code (the data is coming through an ajax call):

```
//routes.js

function validator(req, res, next) {

  req.checkBody('name', 'cannot be empty').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'not valid email').isEmail();

  var errors = req.validationErrors(); // up to here standard express-validator

  // Custom check to see if confirmation email matches.

  if (!errors) errors = [];
  if (email !== email_confirm){
    errors.push({param: 'email_confirm', msg: 'mail does not match!', value: email_confirm})
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.json({msg: 'validation', errors:errors}); // send back the errors
  }
  else {
    // I don't want to insert the email twice in the DB
    delete req.body.email_confirm
    next(); // this will proceed to the post request that inserts data in the db
  }
};
```

So my question is: is there a native method in express-validator to check if (email===email_confirm)? If not is there a better/more standard way to do what I have done above? I'm quite new to node/express in general. Thank you.

Comment: Form validations can be done on the client side javascript itself before sending the request.

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan thanks for the comment. I thought about validating just the emails being equal on the client-side, but since I'm doing validation with express-validator on the server side already I just wanted to keep it all together.

Comment: K fine @Tommy... there are other form validators for express Try this flexible [www.npmjs.com/package/express-form-handler] its similar to jquery form-validator where u can write your own rule and strategy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `express-validator` is `express` middleware for [**validator.js**](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js), you can use [**`equals()`**](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js#validators):

```
req.checkBody('email_confirm', 'mail does not match').equals(req.body.email);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure I tried to use equals before doing my workaround but I must have made some mistake in the syntax because it wasn't working. But well, it does now. Simple and clean thanks!

Answer (score 14):

To achieve this goal with the new check API in express-validator version 4, you would need to create a custom validator function in order to be able to access the request, like this:

```
router.post(
    "/submit",
    [
    // Check validity
    check("password", "invalid password")
        .isLength({ min: 4 })
        .custom((value,{req, loc, path}) => {
            if (value !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
                // trow error if passwords do not match
                throw new Error("Passwords don't match");
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        })
    ],
    (req, res, next) => {
        // return validation results
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        // do stuff
    });
```